# Array for a SQL database using PHP

Tags: php, sql

Can someone please help? I'm new to PHP and struggling to make this bit of code to work. For example I have a sql database table with the following schema and data:

```
Type....rent_price  
a..........100  
b..........200  
c..........300
```

I want to be able to echo say, "a", in one section and "200" in another. The following code will display "a" but then I can't seem to get it to display anything from the rent_price column using a second array.

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM dbc_posts ORDER BY ID ASC limit 3");

for ($set = array (); $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); $set[] = $row['type']);
for ($set1 = array (); $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); $set1[] =$row['rent_price']);
?>

<?php echo $set[0];?>
<?php echo $set1[1];?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You loop through the results twice, without resetting. Try to loop only once:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM dbc_posts ORDER BY ID ASC limit 3");

$set = array ();
$set1 = array ();

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
  $set[] = $row['type'];
  $set1[] =$row['rent_price'];
}
?>

<?php echo $set[0];?>
<?php echo $set1[1];?>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help, this seemed to do exactly what i wanted, thank you

Comment: what happens if only one row is returned ?  ;)

Answer (score 0):

your data is in the first element of array
    $set1[0]

but youre probably better off maintaining the naming throughout

```
$results = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $results[] = $row;
}

foreach ($results as $result){
    echo $result['type'];
    echo $result['rent_price'];
}
```

OR

```
$results = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $results['types'][] = $row['type'];
    $results['rent_prices'][] = $row['rent_price'];

}

foreach ($results['types'] as $type){
    echo $type;
}
foreach ($results['rent_prices'] as $rent_price){
    echo $rent_price;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean by *'"a" in one section and "200" in another'*, you may be able to forgo creating the intermediate arrays and just print the values from your query as you fetch them. Two cells in a table row, for example:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td>$row[type]</td><td>$row[rent_price]</td></tr>";
}
```